# for listing, 'int' object is not iterable in python

Tags: python

it keeps returning me the error 'int' object is not iterable. Any solution?

```
def calculate_average_sales(employee_list):
    for e in employee_list:
        average = sum(e.sales)/len(e.sales)
    print("Average sales of all employees: ",average)

print(calculate_average_sales(employee_list))
```

Comment: Without knowing what exactly `employee_list` is, it's impossible to tell. In the future, be sure to post enough code so that somebody can copy-paste what you have and run it to reproduce the problem. In your case, the problem is that a variable you assumed was a list is actually an int.

Comment: `type(employee_list)`  should return list.

Comment: the list being this:
def init_employee_list(employee_list):
    e = SalesEmployee('101','Angie',1200,15000)
    employee_list.append(e)
    e = SalesEmployee('105','Cindy',1000,12000)
    employee_list.append(e)
    e = SalesEmployee('108','David',1500,20000)
    employee_list.append(e)
    e = SalesEmployee('112','Jason',3000,30000)
    employee_list.append(e)
    e = SalesEmployee('127','Vivian',2000,25000)
    employee_list.append(e)

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `sum` on an `int`, but the signature of `sum` requires it take an iterable as first argument:

```
sum(e.sales) # ???
```

If you tried to call `sum` on, say `3` it'll raise the same exception:

```
>>> sum(3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

You can compute your average without the need to call `sum` on your object. If you have mismatching types in your list, you can do:

```
for e in employee_list:
     if hasattr(e.sales, '__len__'):
        average = sum(e.sales)/len(e.sales)
     else:
        average = e.sales
```

Comment: @Gohboonhuay Seems like he's answered your question, so you should accept the answer and close this question out.

Answer (score 0):

It's very dificult to enswere hance you didn't post the code on employee_list.

in the nats shell , you try to itarate on an int - so if i have to guss the code is somthing like

```
for e in 120: #you wanted to put here some list , but you actualy send numbers
    do something...
```

it's shoul'd work if you do something like this:

```
my_list=[employee_list("name",1000),employee_list("nameb",1000),employee_list("namec",1000),]
```

and then send it to the function like this :

```
calculate_average_sales(my_list)
```

one more thing , `sum` don't work on `int` so maybe this is your problem

```
def calculate_average_sales(employee_list):
    for e in employee_list:
        average = sum(e.sales)/len(e.sales)  #in this line
    print("Average sales of all employees: ",average)
```

this shul'd work ' if not please post the full code here so we will be more helpfull